# Why does $(3)$ have this factorization in $\mathbb{Q}_{(\zeta_3)}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

If I consider the ideal $(2)\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)}$ sage claims it factors as
$$
(-2 \zeta_3^2 - 1)^2
$$
Why is this true? If I multiply the ideal out, I get
\begin{align}
(-2 \zeta_3 - 1)^2 & = 4 \zeta_3 + 4 \zeta_3^2 + 1 \\
& = 4 \zeta_3(1 + \zeta_3) + 1
\end{align}
I don't think this is $3$. For reference, here is the sage code I entered:

```
sage: k = CyclotomicField(3)
sage: k.factor(3)
(Fractional ideal (-2*zeta3 - 1))^2
```

Comment: 2 or 3? ${}{}{}$

Comment: If $x$ is a primitive cube root of $1$, then $1+x+x^2=0$, so that $4x+4x^2+1=-3$.

Comment: If I enter in $2$ it return $2$.

Comment: Okay, since $x^2 + x = -1$ I get the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: If you work in a ring of integers which is monogeneous, there is a theorem of Dedekind (see e.g. Marcus, "Number Fields", chap. 3, thm. 27) which gives you in principle the decomposition of any rational prime. What is the theory behind Sage ? (I know nothing about this)

Comment: @nguyenquangdo I couldn't find the source but it is the function `idealfactor` from pari-gp/Numberfields